# How to add item to cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, zero-subtotal

How to add product to cart with price 0. It is something like an free product add to cart programmatic ally without any cart rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create `events.xml` on the following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
            <observer name="set_custom_price_after_add_to_cart" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Customprice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2. create `Customprice.php` on following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\Customprice.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Customprice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');

        // Get parent product if current product is child product
        $item = ($item->getParentItem()?$item->getParentItem():$item);

        $price = 32; //Set Custom Price Here
     
        //Set custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```